# Does "Abduct" prevent SCVs from building?

Tags: starcraft-2

The new Zerg Viper is able to use "Abduct", pulling allied or enemy units directly to them.

What happens if the abducted target is an SCV in the middle of constructing a command center? Can the SCV be targeted in the first place? Does this cancel the building? Is the player alerted that their building was interrupted? Does the SCV try to continue building after being pulled?

Comment: Great question! I'm not sure because I don't take Vipers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can target and pull SCV's off while they are constructing. I just did it recently. The player is not alerted to the building being interrupted, but is alerted to being attacked. Also note, the construction of the building is not cancelled.

Comment: Do the SCVs try and continue building? or do they stand around dazed/start attacking/running away?

Comment: I did it against the AI and it went back to building right away, so Im unsure if it just went back to building on its own or if the AI auto assigned it back :?

Comment: I have confirmed that any unit that gets abducted gets hit with a "stop" command, so the building won't continue to be constructed unless you reassign an SCV.